# Template hierarchy about pagination after front-page.php

Tags: pagination, archives, homepage, frontpage

Quick, simple. I have `front-page.php` working in Wordpress, and these loops over the main loop for my latest posts. The problem is the pagination template.

When I get to `site.com/page/2`, it shows the same file template `front-page.php`, but with the second round of posts. What I want is to show other file template, like `paged.php`, but not even `archive.php` or `date.php` shows up.

Is there a code for this, instead of writing `if (!is_paged())` wrapping the entire front-page.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to `frontpage_template` and check the `paged` query var, adding your own template when it's beyond the first page. I use `paged.php` in this example:

```
function wpa56889_template_filter( $templates = '' ){
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    if( $paged > 1 ) :
        if( !is_array( $templates ) && !empty( $templates ) ) :
            $templates = locate_template( array( "paged.php", $templates ), false );
        elseif( empty( $templates ) ) :
            $templates = locate_template( "paged.php", false );
        else :
            $new_template = locate_template( array( "paged.php" ) );
            if( !empty( $new_template ) ) array_unshift( $templates, $new_template );
        endif;
    endif;
    return $templates;
}
add_filter( 'frontpage_template', 'wpa56889_template_filter' );
```

Note the [Filter Hierarchy Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy) incorrectly lists the filter as `front_page_template`, but the function that applies this filter appears to sanitize the underscore from the variable before calling it, making it just `frontpage_template`.